# recursive boolean evaluation

Tags: python

Suppose I have something like:

```
[(True, False, False), True] = True
```

or

```
(False, [True, True, False], False) = False
```

that could be infinitely deep and tuples were evaluated as ORs and lists ANDs

How could this function be written in python?

Comment: Recursive short-circuiting traversal function. Have you tried anything?

Comment: If I understand correct, you want to write `X & Y` as `[X, Y]`, and `X | Y` as `(X, Y)`. That (relying on types for evaluations) is not quite a Pythonic way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution with [`all`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) and [`any`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any):

```
def evaluate_bool(expr):
    if isinstance(expr, list):
        return all(evaluate_bool(e) for e in expr)
    elif isinstance(expr, tuple):
        return any(evaluate_bool(e) for e in expr)
    else:
        return expr

evaluate_bool([(True, False, False), True]) # True
evaluate_bool((False, [True, True, False], False)) # False
```

Comment: `map` is eager in Python 2.x--you can keep this lazy by using `itertools.imap` or a generator expression `evaluate_bool(e) for e in expr`. (In Python 3.x `map` is already lazy.)

Comment: @FrancisAvila You are right, this code can be improved by using a generator expression. Thanks!